# Enclose string within braces

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a String of which comes like

```
POC41
POC85
POC71
POC03
```

and I want this to be changed to ('POC41','POC85','POC71','POC03')
For this I use Notepad++ and do find  **\r\n** and replace as **','** and select **Extended** option and replace all. Then I join the string with npp function and get the outcome as **POC41','POC85','POC71','POC03','**

I want the outcome to come as **('POC41','POC85','POC71','POC03')**

Is there any regular expression in notepad++ by which I can achieve like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### This can't be done in a single step.

##### step 1

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(.+)(\R)?`
- Replace with: `'$1'(?2,)`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(.+)        # group 1, 1 or more any character but newline
(\R)?       # group 2, any kind of linebreak, optional
```

**Replacement:**

```
'$1'        # content of group 1 surrounded by single quotes
(?2,)       # condiotnal replacement, if group 2 exists, add a comma
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

##### step 2

- Find what: `^.+$`
- Replace with: `\($0\)`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with one regular expression replace. Select **Regular Expression** and **Wrap around**. Enter `(\A)|(\R*\Z)|(\R)` into the **Find what** and `(?1\(')(?2'\))(?3',')` into the **Replace with", then do a **Replace all**.

Explanation:

```
(\A)               Start of buffer
|              Or
(\R*\Z)            End of buffer, preceeded by zero or more line breaks
|              Or
(\R)               A line break
```

Note that some files (or buffers) have a line break immediately before the
the end-of-buffer (`\Z`), to allow for this a zero or more line breaks (`\R*`) is included.

The replace uses [substitution conditionals](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#substitution-conditionals) so that the start is replaced by the opening bracket and prime, the end by the prime and closing bracket; and, the invervening linebreaks by the prime-comma-prime

```
(?1\(')        If the first alternative matches then replace with open braceket and prime
(?2'\))        If the second alternative matches then replace with prime and close bracket
(?3',')        If the third alternative matches then replace with prime-comma-prime
```

Comment: Nice answer, you do it in one step!

Comment: tried but it did not work for me

Comment: @FuongLee What Notepad++ version was used? What exactly did you do? With what input? What happened and what was the output? Perhaps I omitted some significant option.

Comment: might I used outdated version v7.8.8 (32 bit), I follow up as you mind and use your expression and got this result: 
('P('O('C('4('1('
('P('O('C('8('5('
('P('O('C('7('1('
('P('O('C('0('3('

Comment: I have Notepad++ 8.4.8.

Comment: interesting, let's me update and re-try it

Comment: The repeated `('` suggests that the `\A` is matching too often. Just for fun, you might try replacing the `\A` in the "find what" with a `^`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to selected **Regular Expression** option instead of **Extended**
The result should be

```
'POC41','POC85','POC71','POC03'
```

Finally, add single quotes at the beginning and end of the string manually.

Comment: How is this answering the question?

Comment: Based on different results, what if you choose another option? Don't believe it? Try it and see ?

Comment: The OP asked which regular expression to use, not how to switch to regular expressions

Comment: try with Extended and got results not as expected by using Regular Expression, that why I noted about it to change, keeps the current use "/r/n" because I do not mind that need to be changed, anw can not replace all it by using regular expression for this case by one step, that's all

Answer (score 0):

There is no single regular expression you can write, but you can do it in multiple steps.
Copy & paste below and search/replace in that order.

**Separate by , and put in one line**

Find: `(POC[^\s]+)(\s+)`
Replace: `'$1',`

**Find first and add bracket**

Find: `^'POC`
Replace: `\('POC`

**Find last and add ' and bracket**

Find: `(POC[\d]+)$`
Replace: `$1'\)`